# Deploying Node.js app on Heroku successful on locally but shows Error: Cannot find module '/app/server' online

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I'm new to Heroku. I have the following file structure for my app. It can successfully run if I run node server or heroku local web. I have the following script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server"
  },
```

Also, I add a Procfile with

```
web: node server.js
```

[image: Here's the file structure pic]

However, when I run Heroku open, it shows the following error. How Can I fix the problem?
[image: Here's the error log]

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a file called server.js under app, you need to rename the require stack so that the path is right...